Issues with bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js and CSP headers in AngularJS project
I am using the bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js library in my AngularJS project. I have imported the library in my cshtml file, but I am facing issues with the modal popup. When the popup opens, the buttons (Next, Previous, Slideshow, Download) are hidden due to the hide, fade, and modal classes.
If I manually remove the hidden attribute, the buttons become visible, but clicking them does not trigger their respective functionalities. Additionally, I am using the following Content Security Policy (CSP) headers in my web.config :
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' http: https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"/>

Cshtml file
<link href="~/Scripts/plugins/Bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/plugins/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/infragistics/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/CustomCss/iggrid_mod.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/load-image.min.js"></script>


<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ip.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/locale.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/FileUpload/main.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/infragistics/iggrid_small.min.js"></script>
<div id="FileUploadPopupDiv" class="container-fluid" ng-controller="fileAttachement">
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <form id="fileupload" action="~/Areas/PhysicalRegister/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin: 2px;" class="well">
                <input type="hidden" id="GuidValue" name="GuidValue" value="{{guid}}" />
                <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
                <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                    <div class="span7">
                        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                        <span id="addFilesButton" class="btn btn-minier btn-round btn-success fileinput-button">
                            <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                            <span>Add files...</span>
                            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                        </span>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-round btn-minier btn-warning cancel">
                            <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                            <span>Cancel upload</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span5" id="myprogress">
                        <!-- The global progress bar -->
                        <div class="progress pos-rel active fade">
                            <!--[if lte IE 9]>
                    <span>File is uploading please wait...</span>
                <![endif]-->
                            <div class="bar" style="width: 0%; height: 120%">
                                <img src="~/Images/lightGreen.png" alt="image comming up...." width="100%" height="100%" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
                <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                    <!-- The global progress bar -->
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active"
                         role="progressbar"
                         aria-valuemin="0"
                         aria-valuemax="100">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
                             style="width: 0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                    <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody>
                </table>

                <!-- modal-gallery is the modal dialog used for the image gallery -->
                <div id="modal-gallery" class="modal modal-gallery hide fade">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                        <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="modal-image"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary modal-next">
                            <span>**Next**</span>
                            <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-info modal-prev">
                            <i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i>
                            <span>**Previous**</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-success modal-play modal-slideshow" data-slideshow="5000">
                            <i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>
                            <span>**Slideshow**</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn modal-download" target="_blank">
                            <i class="icon-download"></i>
                            <span>**Download**</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-minier btn-primary" ng-click="hitSubmit();">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Upload</span>
                </button>
                <button ng-if="doneUploadButton" type="button" class="btn btn-minier btn-primary" ng-click="doneUpload()"><i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i><span>Done</span></button>
                <div ng-bind-html="loadingImage | trusted_html" id="spinnerGifDiv"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="grid-file-attchment" grid-load grid-height="0.25" grid-data-source="fileAttachments" grid-column-def="gridFileAttachmentColumnDef" grid-features="gridFileAttachmentFeatures">
                <table id="fileAttachmentGrid" class="table table-bordered"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
              <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% 
        for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}" height="42" width="42"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
@*            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
            </button>*@
            <input type="text" placeholder="Description" id="fileDesc_{%=file.name%}"></input>
@*            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">*@
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>


bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js File
(function(a){"use strict",typeof define=="function"&&define.amd?define(["jquery","./load-image.js","bootstrap"],a):a(window.jQuery,window.loadImage)})(function(a,b){"use strict",a.extend(a.fn.modal.defaults,{delegate:document,selector:null,index:0,href:null,preloadRange:2,offsetWidth:100,offsetHeight:200,canvas:!1,slideshow:0});var c=a.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.show,d=a.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.hide;a.extend(a.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype,{initLinks:function(){var b=this,c=this.options,d=c.selector||"a[data-target="+c.target+"]",e=0;a(c.delegate).find(d).each(function(d,f){var g=f.href||a(f).data("href");b.urls[b.urls.length-1]!==g&&(b.urls.push(g),b.titles.push(f.title),g===c.href&&(c.index=e),e+=1)}),this.urls[c.index]||(c.index=0)},startSlideShow:function(){var a=this;this.options.slideshow&&(this._slideShow=window.setTimeout(function(){a.next()},this.options.slideshow))},stopSlideShow:function(){window.clearTimeout(this._slideShow)},toggleSlideShow:function(){var a=this.$element.find(".modal-slideshow");this.options.slideshow?(this.options.slideshow=0,this.stopSlideShow()):(this.options.slideshow=a.data("slideshow")||5e3,this.startSlideShow()),a.find("i").toggleClass("icon-play icon-pause")},preloadImages:function(){var b=this.options,c=b.index+b.preloadRange+1,d,e;for(e=b.index-b.preloadRange;e<c;e+=1)d=this.urls[e],d&&e!==b.index&&a("<img>").prop("src",d)},loadImage:function(){var a=this,c=this.$element,d=this.options.index,e;this.abortLoad(),this.stopSlideShow(),this._loadingTimeout=window.setTimeout(function(){c.addClass("modal-loading")},100),e=c.find(".modal-image").children().removeClass("in"),window.setTimeout(function(){e.remove()},3e3),c.find(".modal-title").text(this.titles[d]),c.find(".modal-download").prop("href",this.urls[d]),this.loadingImage=b(this.urls[d],function(b){window.clearTimeout(a._loadingTimeout),c.removeClass("modal-loading"),a.showImage(b),a.startSlideShow()},a.loadImageOptions),this.preloadImages()},showImage:function(b){var c=this.$element,d=a.support.transition&&c.hasClass("fade"),e=d?c.animate:c.css,f=c.find(".modal-image"),g,h;f.css({width:b.width,height:b.height}),a(window).width()>480&&(d&&(g=c.clone().hide().appendTo(document.body)),e.call(c.stop(),{"margin-top":-((g||c).outerHeight()/2),"margin-left":-((g||c).outerWidth()/2)}),g&&g.remove()),f.append(b),h=b.offsetWidth,a(b).addClass("in")},abortLoad:function(){this.loadingImage&&(this.loadingImage.onload=this.loadingImage.onerror=null),window.clearTimeout(this._loadingTimeout)},prev:function(){var a=this.options;a.index-=1,a.index<0&&(a.index=this.urls.length-1),this.loadImage()},next:function(){var a=this.options;a.index+=1,a.index>this.urls.length-1&&(a.index=0),this.loadImage()},keyHandler:function(a){switch(a.which){case 37:case 38:a.preventDefault(),this.prev();break;case 39:case 40:a.preventDefault(),this.next()}},wheelHandler:function(a){a.preventDefault(),a=a.originalEvent,this._wheelCounter=this._wheelCounter||0,this._wheelCounter+=a.wheelDelta||a.detail||0;if(a.wheelDelta&&this._wheelCounter>=120||!a.wheelDelta&&this._wheelCounter<0)this.prev(),this._wheelCounter=0;else if(a.wheelDelta&&this._wheelCounter<=-120||!a.wheelDelta&&this._wheelCounter>0)this.next(),this._wheelCounter=0},initGalleryEvents:function(){var b=this,c=this.$element;c.find(".modal-image").on("click.modal-gallery",function(a){a.altKey?b.prev(a):b.next(a)}),c.find(".modal-prev").on("click.modal-gallery",function(a){b.prev(a)}),c.find(".modal-next").on("click.modal-gallery",function(a){b.next(a)}),c.find(".modal-slideshow").on("click.modal-gallery",function(a){b.toggleSlideShow(a)}),a(document).on("keydown.modal-gallery",function(a){b.keyHandler(a)}).on("mousewheel.modal-gallery, DOMMouseScroll.modal-gallery",function(a){b.wheelHandler(a)})},destroyGalleryEvents:function(){var b=this.$element;this.abortLoad(),this.stopSlideShow(),b.find(".modal-image, .modal-prev, .modal-next, .modal-slideshow").off("click.modal-gallery"),a(document).off("keydown.modal-gallery").off("mousewheel.modal-gallery, DOMMouseScroll.modal-gallery")},show:function(){if(!this.isShown&&this.$element.hasClass("modal-gallery")){var b=this.$element,d=this.options,e=a(window).width(),f=a(window).height();this.urls=[],this.titles=[],b.hasClass("modal-fullscreen")?this.loadImageOptions={minWidth:e,minHeight:f,maxWidth:e,maxHeight:f,canvas:d.canvas}:this.loadImageOptions={maxWidth:e-d.offsetWidth,maxHeight:f-d.offsetHeight,canvas:d.canvas},e>480&&b.css({"margin-top":-(b.outerHeight()/2),"margin-left":-(b.outerWidth()/2)}),this.initGalleryEvents(),this.initLinks(),this.urls.length&&this.loadImage()}c.apply(this,arguments)},hide:function(){this.isShown&&this.$element.hasClass("modal-gallery")&&(this.options.delegate=document,this.options.href=null,this.destroyGalleryEvents()),d.apply(this,arguments)}}),a(function(){a(document.body).on("click.modal-gallery.data-api",'[data-toggle="modal-gallery"]',function(b){var c=a(this),d=c.data(),e=a(d.target),f=e.data("modal"),g;f||(d=a.extend(e.data(),d)),d.selector||(d.selector="a[rel=gallery]"),g=a(b.target).closest(d.selector),g.length&&e.length&&(b.preventDefault(),d.href=g.prop("href")||g.data("href"),d.delegate=g[0]!==this?this:document,f&&a.extend(f.options,d),e.modal(d))})})});

What I Have Tried:

Removing hide, fade, and modal classes: The buttons become visible, but clicking them does not trigger any functionality.
Checked the browser console for errors.
Verified that all JavaScript files are loaded correctly.
Ensured that the modal is being triggered and shown correctly.

Frontend image

So if you remove the CSP, everything is working as it should then?

No, even after removing the CSP, the problem persists. The buttons (Next, Previous, Slideshow, Download) do become visible after removing the hide, fade, and modal classes, but their functionality is still not working. The buttons are not clickable, so I can't verify if the setTimeout function is working correctly. To check if the issue is related to the CSP header, the buttons need to be clickable first, which they currently are not.
